# Watson Speech to Text : How set my username and password on windows 10

Tags: curl, ibm-cloud, speech-to-text

Thank you for open this page.

I want to transcribe a lecture meeting's audio files to texts with Speech to Text  and get texts in curl.

Maybe I have an elementary error.
I read official Bluemix documents, But I couldn't understand them.

I already got my Service credentials.
But I couldn't set them.

I tried set them like this.

An example on Bluemix official documents>>

```
curl -X POST -u {username}:{password}
--header "Content-Type: audio/flac"
--header "Transfer-Encoding: chunked"
--data-binary @{path}audio-file.flac
"https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?continuous=true"
```

Tried 1>>

```
curl -X POST -u "\"username\":\"password\""
--header "Content-Type: audio/flac"
--header "Transfer-Encoding: chunked"
--data-binary @{path}audio-file.flac
"https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?continuous=true"
```

Tried 2>>

```
curl -X POST -u 'username':'password\'
--header "Content-Type: audio/flac"
--header "Transfer-Encoding: chunked"
--data-binary @{path}audio-file.flac
"https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?continuous=true"
```

this code has following error and not working.

> Warning: Couldn't read data from file
>   "{path}audio-file.flac", Warning: this makes an empty
>   POST. curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in
>   certificate chain More details here:
>   http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

Besides I don't know where should I put my audio files and from where should I path to the files.
I path to them from terminal's pwd and I put them on my local directory. Is it wrong?

Could you give me your advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the absolute path to your audio file.

For instance (if the files were in my current directory):

```
curl -X POST -u "myusername":"mypassword" --header "Content-Type: audio/flac" --data-binary "@audio-file1.flac" --data-binary "@audio-file2.flac" "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?timestamps=true&word_alternatives_threshold=0.9&keywords=%22colorado%22%2C%22tornado%22%2C%22tornadoes%22&keywords_threshold=0.5&continuous=true"
```

[Sample Audio Files](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/speech-to-text/api/v1/audio-files.zip)